# Knockout-Kendo ListView not updating in IE when using a Knockout Template

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have a KendoUI listview bound to a Knockout ObservableArray and Template using the Knockout-Kendo plugin. When I push a new item to the ObservableArray, the Kendo ListView doesn't update when viewed in IE7-8. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

What is kinda weird is if I log to the console, I see the observable array has a length > 0. But, if I put a breakpoint after the viewmodel is bound and the array has been populated by a api call, the length is 0 even though the console entry just told me the length is > 0.

Here is the binding:

```
<div id="lvBill" data-bind="kendoListView: { data: accounts, template: 'listTmpl', useKOTemplates: true }"></div>
```

Here is the template:

```
<!-- Template for list -->
<script id="listTmpl" type="text/html">
    <div class="savedBills">
        <!-- ko if: fileThumbnail -->
        <div style="padding: 1px 1px 2px 1px; background-color: black">
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: fileThumbnail }" />
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <div class="savedBillInfo">
            <h3><span data-bind="text: carrier"></span></h3>
            <h3><span data-bind="text: accountNumber"></span></h3>

            <p><span data-bind="currencyString: billAmount"></span></p>
            <p><span data-bind="dateString: billDate"></span></p>
            <span style="float: right"><a data-bind="click: $root.deleteAccount"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```